# Get the real video URL from a url

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm trying to get the real file URL from a url that doesn't show up the real file name.

My url is like this `http://video.premium.com/file/ee7bfec921cfbe16e6f08e282992b99670a00ca3/3`

If I could get the real file url I could stream it directly online through a web player, but it needs .mp4 or other file format to play, just the url `http://video.premium.com/file/ee7bfec921cfbe16e6f08e282992b99670a00ca3/3` doesnt work.

but when I open the URL using VLC media player, it works. doesn't work with online flash or other players..

Is this even possible? Anyway to do this?

Comment: download fiddler and then run the url in your browser...fiddler will let you examine the data.

Comment: Not every URL needs a file extension. It could be that that really is the file.

Comment: @highwingers : I installed fiddler and tried to inspect the url, fiddler shows the video information also but not the real path, i mean temporally path with the file extension.

Comment: @icktoofay: No, in this case, it needs an extension to play the file, I dont know whats wrong, but it doesnt play with any web player but it works with VLC media player..

Comment: @naveencgr8: What I'm saying is that if it doesn't have an extension, you can't get a URL with an extension. You just have to deal with the fact that it has no extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With **curl**, use this: It follows the redirect until it finds the endpoint. In the included code I used goo.gl to shorten the url to a rando image. You will see the output is the original link (and it would output whatever number of redirects and their URLs), and the final redirect to the actual file. I think this is what you are looking for. I did not write this originally, but found it somewhere some time ago and reused it many times again with tweaking when needed. It seems to fit well in many places. Glad to pass it on. I think it might help to achieve what you are looking for.

```
<?php
function follow_redirect($url){
   $redirect_url = null;


   if(function_exists("curl_init")){
      $ch = curl_init($url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      $response = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
   }
   else{
      $url_parts = parse_url($url);
      $sock = fsockopen($url_parts['host'], (isset($url_parts['port']) ? (int)$url_parts['port'] : 80));
      $request = "HEAD " . $url_parts['path'] . (isset($url_parts['query']) ? '?'.$url_parts['query'] : '') . " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
      $request .= 'Host: ' . $url_parts['host'] . "\r\n";
      $request .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
      fwrite($sock, $request);
      $response = fread($sock, 2048);
      fclose($sock);
   }


   $header = "Location: ";
   $pos = strpos($response, $header);
   if($pos === false){
      return false;
   }
   else{
      $pos += strlen($header);
      $redirect_url = substr($response, $pos, strpos($response, "\r\n", $pos)-$pos);
      return $redirect_url;
   }
}

$url = 'http://goo.gl/66VJB';


echo '<ol>';
while(($newurl = follow_redirect($url)) !== false){
   echo '<li>', $url, '</li>';
   $url = $newurl;
}
echo '</ol>';


echo '<a href="', $url, '">', $url, '</a>';
?>
```

Output:

1. http://goo.gl/66VJB

http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_XE0TDW07Noo/TOSVQXZtgAI/AAAAAAAAELo/aG80jZ7u_fo/s1600/aptitude_test.gif

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works like charm but in my case its not working, I think its something with filehosting site.. but I'll try my best.. :)

Comment: Glad to help where I could :-) Good luck!